# Why is ng2-nouislider element value not updated when using the same control on another input?

Tags: angular, forms

I have a problem with the angular package called [ng2-nouislider](https://github.com/tb/ng2-nouislider) when I try to use it with forms.

I have the same form control attached to a simple input and a nouislider element. They both set the form control value separately, but they don't affect each other's value. How should I set up my form so that when I change the value in the input, the slider gets updated too with the new value (and the same for the other way)?

I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-nouislider-with-form) project for this.

Here is the code I use:

html:

```
<code>form disabled: {{ form.get('single').disabled }}</code>
<br>
<code>form value: {{ form.get('single').value }}</code>
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" [formControl]="form.get('single')">
  <nouislider [min]="0" [max]="10" [step]="0.1 [formControl]="form.get('single')"></nouislider>
</form>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary (click)="toggleDisabled()">
    {{form.get('single').disabled ? 'Enable': 'Disable'}}
  </button>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 'single': [3] });
    // this.watchFormChanges();
  }

  watchFormChanges() {
    this.form.get('single').valueChanges
      .pipe(debounceTime(300))
      .subscribe(v => {
        this.form.get('single').setValue(v, { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false });
      });
  }

  toggleDisabled() {
    const control = this.form.get('single');
    control.enabled ? control.disable() : control.enable();
  }
}
```

Funny part is that disabling works on both, and if you use the commented out method call it works because we set the control value manually.

So my question is, am I doing something wrong here? What do I do so that my commented out code is not necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong. Apparently, this is by design: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13792.

The suggested workaround by people there is watching the form control for value changes and updating it manually, which is what you've already come up with. That seems to be the only way for now.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually not supposed to reference the same `FormControl` from two different `FormControlDirective`. Angular is not designed to do that, so you'll have to keep your workaround (or look for a cleaner one if it doesn't suit your needs).